# Conic optimization in finance

Tags: optimization

Linear programming and quadratic programming are types of convex optimization that are often used.

Does conic optimization or programming have any applications in finance? Or for where the previous types of problems are converted to conic, and why?

An overview of a chosen financial model's formulation as a conic optimization problem would be helpful, not just pdf links from search.

Comment: https://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/cvx_portfolio.pdf

Comment: Cones are convex, whence conic optimization is a subfield of convex optimization.

Comment: yes, do you know of any

Comment: A few examples, not necessarily finance, in section 4 of the [SDPT3 whitepaper](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2010/06/2654.pdf).